# Create Start and End Dates based on record Modification Date and Active Flag

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to create Start and End dates (Effective dates) based on a table that has a primary key ContactID, ModificationDate, and StateCode.  The ModificationDate represents when the record was entered or updated, the StateCode represents if the record is enabled or disabled.

I am trying to figure out the Start (StateCode = 0) and End (StateCode=1) dates of each Contact record but can't quite get the query down.

I've tried using combinations of Windows Functions like Row_Number, Rank, Lead, etc but can't figure out how to increment the grouping number when StateCode = 1.

```
CREATE TABLE Contact(
  ContactID INTEGER,
  StateCode INTEGER,
  ModifiedOn Datetime)

  INSERT INTO Contact
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/1/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/2/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 1, '7/3/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/4/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/5/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 1, '7/6/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/7/2019' UNION
  SELECT 1, 0, '7/8/2019'
```

Sample SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8aca/45

Based on the changes of StateCode in my example, I expect to see 3 records.

```
ContactID, StartDate, EndDate, ActiveFlag
1, 7/1/2019, 7/3/2019, 0
1, 7/4/2019, 7/6/2019, 0
1, 7/7/2019, NULL, 1
```

Potential Solution I am validating

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
  LAG(StateCode,1,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY ModifiedOn) AS IsStart
  , StateCode AS IsEnd
  , ContactID
  , StateCode
  , ModifiedOn  
FROM Contact       
), CTE2 AS(
SELECT 
  ContactID
  , IsStart
  , IsEnd  
  , ModifiedOn  
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsStart = 1 THEN ModifiedOn END) AS StartTest2
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsEnd = 1 THEN ModifiedOn END) AS EndTest2
FROM CTE
WHERE IsStart = 1 OR IsEnd = 1
)
SELECT 
  Start.ContactID  
  , Start.ModifiedOn AS StartDate
  , EndDates.ModifiedOn AS EndDate
FROM CTE2 AS Start
   LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS EndDates
     ON Start.ContactID = EndDates.ContactID
     AND Start.StartTest2 = EndDates.EndTest2
WHERE Start.StartTest2 <> 1
ORDER BY Start.ModifiedOn
```

Comment: Google "SQL Gaps and Islands problem" for examples/ideas.

Comment: I'm looking at the examples from this search, and it brings me back to the same dilemma.  I can't figure out how to use StateCode to distinguish the groups and restart the date gaps.  It's easy if I'm just looking at the dates, but I'm not seeing an example that's using a condition based on another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using a LAG function to set a flag for the StartDates and setting a flag for EndDates by the StateCode itself.  Then I did some conditional logic on a DENSE_RANK function for both Start and End flags to get the actual dates associated to the date-periods.  Here's my code (needs formatting still).

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    CASE WHEN StateCode = 1 THEN 0 ELSE (LAG(StateCode,1,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY ModifiedOn ASC)) END AS IsStartDate
  , CASE WHEN (LAG(StateCode,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY ModifiedOn ASC)) IS NULL OR (LAG(StateCode,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY ModifiedOn ASC)) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE StateCode END AS IsEndDate
  , ContactID
  , StateCode
  , ModifiedOn  
FROM Contact       
), CTE2 AS(
SELECT 
  ContactID
  , IsStartDate
  , IsEndDate  
  , ModifiedOn  
  , CASE WHEN IsStartDate = 0 THEN -1 ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsStartDate = 1 THEN ModifiedOn END ASC) END AS StartRank
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CASE WHEN IsEndDate = 1 THEN ModifiedOn END ASC) AS EndRank
FROM CTE
WHERE IsStart = 1 OR IsEnd = 1
)
SELECT 
  Start.ContactID  
  , Start.ModifiedOn AS StartDate
  , EndDates.ModifiedOn AS EndDate
FROM CTE2 AS Start
   LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS EndDates
     ON Start.ContactID = EndDates.ContactID
     AND Start.StartRank = EndDates.EndRank
WHERE Start.StartRank <> -1
ORDER BY Start.ModifiedOn
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use either LAG() or a self-join to grab a reference to the previous row.

If the current row's `StateCode` is 0, and the previous row's is either NULL (first row) or 1, then this row's date is a "StartDate".   If the reverse is true, then it's an "EndDate".   If both row's have the same `StateCode`, then just ignore the row.

Comment: Thanks. This is the route I was going.  I'm updating my question with a potential solution that I am now validating.  It's ugly so I'd appreciate feedback if there's a better way to do it (or if it's not working like I think!). Thank you!!!